# How should I load and change settings?

Tags: vb.net, settings

Please forgive me if my thought process is incorrect. I'm only a programmer in my spare time, with no formal training.

I'm using VB.net to create a very basic application, but some settings need to be read  on startup. So my theory is that in the `Form1.Load` area, add all the checks for various settings and apply the settings as needed.

Next, changing settings on the fly while the application is running. I see a few different possibilities:

1. Create subroutines for each setting check. As each checkbox or radio button is clicked, call the appropriate sub-routine. As the form loads, run through all these subroutines.
2. Call the `Form1.Load` subroutine on any settings change (larger programs, I could see this being VERY slow)
3. Repeat myself, and execute the code as soon as the option is changed. Have the `Form1.Load` subroutine execute the settings check on every control, and remember to add newer settings to the sub as they get built or changed.

Option 1 seems to be the most logical in my head. **Is this the most sustainable method for projects, or is there a better way to ensure settings change as the options change?**

For example, I have a checkbox that controls whether the output window is a Fixed Width font, or a regular font. The check box gets and saves its settings to the `App.config` file, so the option is persistent across program starts.

Comment: You can actually bind Winforms controls to application settings. It seems daunting at first, but it's actually really easy once you get it.

Comment: @RubberDuck details? I'd love to learn easier methods

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371118/automatically-update-the-application-setting-using-the-binding-from-vs-net-desig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from RubberDuck's comments, I am able to use the Application Settings function built in to the .NET framework.

This is handling all the on-the-fly changes, as well as persistent changes throughout the program.

On each control that I want to change the settings with, I start by assigning the setting for the control. Then, I run the logic (i.e. If setting is true, set property x to y). Finally, I update the controls that get affected by the settings.

I then attach the setting to be changed to the control, and it handles everything on the fly.